# Issues After Upgrading PhoneGap to 1.4.1

Tags: cordova

Ive been encountering this problem since I last upgraded PhoneGap from 1.3.0 to 1.4.1, the issue is after the upgrade, I cannot somehow connect to my database or something. it gives me an error within the app "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" and "TypeError: Cannot read property 'contacts' of undefined".

Comment: Could you add some code about de 'contacts' property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you update your projects resources to point to the new phonegap.1.4.1.jar file that was included? I had this problem on a project when one of the developers replaced the .js but not the jar and the android app was compiling with the old sources.

Comment: I have updated my project and followed the instructions carefully that was included in the download of PhoneGap. but as I update to phonegap. then there comes that error. :(

Comment: so you right-clicked your project in eclipse, went to properties, then to java build path, then replaced the old .jar with the new one?

Answer (score 2):

When you upgraded to 1.4.1 did you make a new project or are you still using the one from 1.3.0?

If you didn't create a new project, inside the dmg you installed PhoneGap should be a file called "PhoneGap Upgrade Guide.pdf". It should help you upgrade your project.

1.4.1 had some significant changes in it that require a fresh new project, unfortunately.

Comment: I am still using the one from 1.3.0, where should I locate the "PhoneGap Upgrade Guide.pdf"? sorry, Im new at PhoneGap. But thank you for your response.

Comment: When you downloaded PhoneGap the installer was inside a .dmg file called PhoneGap-1.4.1.dmg. Also in that .dmg is the "PhoneGap Upgrade Guide.pdf".

Comment: Im really really sorrry for my noobness. but i dont see any PhoneGap-1.4.1.dmg. the one I downloaded is actually "callback-phonegap-1.4.0.zip", that is the file

Comment: Inside that zip is lib/ios/PhoneGap-1.4.1.dmg - this is what you would have used to install PhoneGap for iOS, yes? ... Secondly, you would be best off downloading 1.4.1 as it fixes a serious bug in orientation on iOS.

Comment: I see it. but im not developing in IOS. my project is actually an android project. Thank you for your responses sir.

Comment: Ah hah. I Apologise... I went off in a direction on an assumption. For Android, all you should need to do is make sure you are linking to the correct jar file and use the new javascript file instead of the one from 1.3.0.

Comment: ok2. Thank you. so I guess I have already installed PhoneGap successfully. but why am i recievin that error? is there any way for me to bypass the login privilege? or temporarily disable the connection with my DB for me to play within the application?